# boost::asio::buffer with vectors structs

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I have 2 problems:

1. In my info structure if I have `float` or `double` types instead of `std::string` it works fine, but if I use `std::string` as below, in my client part i receive the struct but after that it just crashes.
2. I can`t even send it using`std::vector`, like this:

---

```
struct info
{
    int id;
    std::string name;
};


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint ep(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 12345);
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket cl1(ios);

    cl1.open(ep.protocol());
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    cl1.connect(ep, ec);
    if (ec == 0)
        cout << "Connected" << endl;
    else {

        cout << "Not connected" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return -2;
    }

    info student;
    student.id = 7;
    student.name = "Rasul";

    cl1.send(boost::asio::buffer(&student, sizeof(student)));

    if (ec == 0)
        cout << "Written" << endl;
    else {

        cout << "Not written" << endl;
        system("pause");
        return -2;
    }
    cout << "Done" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 2->

"info st1;
  st1.id = 0; 
  st1.name = "abd";
  vector<info> st;
  st.push_back(st1);
  cl1.send(boost::asio::buffer(&st, sizeof(st)));
       **--> sending , but not 
    receiving in client "read" method;
    " if i use std::array it works but not with std::vector in the same way
please help me, where am i doing wrong???
Thank you in advance**

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read **[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)** and fix the problems in your question. For even more help asking here, check out the **[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tour)** and the rest of the **[help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/)**.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. In my info structure if I have `float` or `double` types instead of `std::string` it works fine, but if I use `std::string` as below, in my client part i receive the struct but after that it just crashes.

That's because `float` or `double` are POD data types and `std::string` is not, violating the contract:

> *The `boost::asio::buffer` function is used to create a buffer object to represent raw memory, an array of POD elements, a vector of POD elements, or a `std::string`*

To be precise, they mean *"[a (array|vector) of POD elements] or [a `std::string`]"*, which is clear when you look at the [list of overloads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/buffer.html)

Add a static assertion and you'll see:

```
static_assert(std::is_pod<info>::value, "whoops, that can't work");
cl1.send(boost::asio::buffer(&student, sizeof(student)));
```

If you want to serialize this you'll have to write some code. Assuming architecture independence and portability in general are not an issue¹, you could:

```
int32_t id_and_size[] = {student.id, static_cast<int32_t>(student.name.length())};
assert(id_and_size[1] >= 0); // because `size_t` is unsigned and larger than int32_t

cl1.send(boost::asio::buffer(id_and_size));
cl1.send(boost::asio::buffer(student.name.data(), student.name.length()));
```

This sends the length separate from the data: **<kbd>Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/897573028a86e16e)</kbd>**

00000000: 0700 0000 0500 0000 5261 7375 6c         ........Rasul

Though this is error-prone and tedious. If you control both ends, consider a serialization framework (Boost Serialization, Google Protobuf...)

¹ since you already mention serializing raw binary form of `double` etc.